# Webpart is in edit mode?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have a webpart in a page and I need to know how I can determine if the page is currently in edit mode. For example: `if(Page.IsInEditMode)`.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the class System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager

It has an **EditDisplayMode** property that represents the display mode in which end users can edit and modify server controls. See doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.editdisplaymode.aspx)